# Solve not working now, but did befoe

Tags: syntax

[image: Solve problem]

I did this Solve earlier and it worked. Why is it not working now?
I tried other solves after this one, and did not work, also.
I tried creating a new notebook, and it did not work there, also.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Your version information might be helpful.  Have you tried `Clear[r]` and then re-executing the `Solve` command?

Comment: My version is 11.3.

Comment: I did Clear[r] and it still did not work.

Comment: Solve[-2 r^2 - 3 r^4 + r^5 - 2 r Sqrt[r^2 + 3 r^4] == 0, r, Reals]

Comment: Maybe the cell is queued, because another cell is evaluating

Comment: I cannot get any command to work. So, I am reinstalling Mathematica.

Comment: After reinstalling Mathematica I  cannot get even 2+4 to work! It again states that it has a running evaluation.